# When can か振り and 振り be used?

Tags: grammar, suffixes, particle-か

I know Ｖ辞書形 + 振り means "pretending to do V", as in

> 僕を気付かなかった振りをして、僕をただ通り過ぎた。

However, I've recently come to know the expression [知]{し}ったか[振]{ぶ}り, but why is that か there? It seems to have exactly the same meaning as 知った振り, so are they interchangeable? Are there any other expressions that are constructed like that?

Comment: `僕を気付かなかった振りをして` -> 「僕**に**気づかなかったふりをして」since 気づく takes に, not を.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that 知った振り and 知ったか振り are basically interchangeable, but 知ったか振り is a little more frequently used in everyday conversation or daily situations than 知った振り. These are the examples found on the web.

- 知ったかぶりをする男性って本当にうざいと思う。
- 女性の知ったかぶりは、場合によってはかわいく思える。
- 同僚の知ったかぶりには、いつもイライラさせられる。
- 大事な仕事で知ったかぶりをされると、トラブルにつながる。
- 「知ったかぶり」は印象が悪い

Of course, all of these are used with a nuance of criticizing somebody. But this may be true of 知った振り.

And we have no definite etymology of this expression, but I have guessed this etymological process.

1. 知っている**か**のような振りをする。
2. 知っている**か**の振りをする。
3. 知った**か**振りをする。

or, more likely

1. 知った**か**のごとき振りをする。
2. 知った**か**の振りをする。
3. 知った**か**振りをする。

Lastly, though I have not done enough research, there will be any other expressions constructed like that.